# Uber deeplink on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to add uber deep linking into my app on Android.

I am creating the intent as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, deepLink.getDeeplinkUri());
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

The computed Uri I am sending through is this:

```
uber://?action=setPickup&product_id=91901472-f30d-4614-8ba7-9fcc937cebf5&pickup[latitude]=-33.9226277&pickup[longitude]=18.4232182&dropoff[latitude]=-33.972282&dropoff[longitude]=18.601956
```

It then launches the Uber app, selects the correct product, but it is not picking up the dropoff location at all.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution. You need to also send through the pickup[nickname] and dropoff[nickname] before it will display anything in the uber app

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to attache `product_id`.
Attaching it did the trick without nicknames